# Free Shipping AND Discout on a Product? - Magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping, coupon

Yesterday I did setup a cart price rule where you get free shipping on subtotal which is over 100$.
That works so far.

Now I wanted to make a coupon where I get 5$ discout on a specific product + free shipping. 
If I apply the couponcode, the discoumt works fine, but there still are shipping costs.
Its also strange that when I have an order over 100$ with free shipping and I add the coupon code, I get the 5$ discount BUT also shipping costs, even tho the  order is over 100$ anyway..

[image]
[image]

Thanks everyone!

Comment: How and Where you set free shipping over $100?

Comment: I did create cart price rule aswell. That works so far, but for the other cart price rule, where I want free shipping + discount, kinda doesnt work. only the discount gets applied..